# How to force the misalignment of subscript and superscript

Tags: math-mode

`${\Lambda^a}_b$` compiles to the desired result:

[image]

However, if I want to add both superscript and subscript on `$\Bar{\Lambda}$`, the superscript and subscript always align:

[image]

I tried to add braces on different locations, but these attempts do not work, and they all compiles to the result above. `\Bar` is in `amsmath`, using `\bar` in native LaTeX does not work either.

```
{\Bar{\Lambda}^a}_b
{{\Bar\Lambda}^a}_b
{{\Bar{\Lambda}}^a}_b
```

How can I force the superscript and subscript misalign in this situation?

A compilable minimal example:

```
\documentclass[utf8]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}

Aligned superscript and subscript:

$$
\Lambda_a^b, \bar{\Lambda}_a^b
$$

Misaligned superscript and subscript:

$$
{\Lambda_a}^b, \text{This does not work: } {\bar{\Lambda}_a}^b
$$


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! How is `\Bar` defined? Also, it is in general better if you provide a complete minimal example (one that compiles).

Comment: @egreg Thanks, it works. Would you like to answer this question so that I can accept the answer?

Comment: @mickep `\Bar` comes from `amsmath`. The example has been added.

Comment: @lfx Never use `$$`. See the addendum to my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is mostly a FAQ, but perhaps not for the particular case. You need to add an empty atom, otherwise the braces around the accented atom would be removed.

But you can also exploit the `tensor` package and get even better spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}

We can get the subscript and superscript not aligned with standard methods
\[
{\Lambda^{a}}_{b} \quad {{}\bar{\Lambda}^{a}}_{b}
\]
but we can exploit the \texttt{tensor} package
\[
\tensor{\Lambda}{^{a}_{b}} \quad \tensor{\bar{\Lambda}}{^{a}_{b}}
\]
and even get better horizontal spacing (look closely).

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note 1.** `\Bar` and `\bar` are completely equivalent with `amsmath`, that defines the former for back compatibility with former versions where the two commands did different things: the capitalized version was used for correctly staggering accents vertically.

**Note 2.** NEVER use `$$` in a LaTeX `document` environment, see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

**Note 3.** Never leave a blank line before a math display.